# Vue cli remove script injection

Tags: javascript, wordpress, vue.js, vue-cli

I am using vue cli within wordpress. Wordpress has it's own way of adding scripts to the DOM. Because of this I do not need vue cli to add the script the final index.html file. When I run npm run build I get something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <title>my-app</title>
  <link href="/js/app.js" rel="preload" as="script"><link href="/js/chunk-vendors.js" rel="preload" as="script"></head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but my-app doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/chunk-vendors.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

I want when I run build to not have the tags and css injected. What's happening is when the html file is run I get a bunch of 404 errors. So it would be great if there is a way to stop the injection completely but still build the actual bundle files.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by disabling injection in the [HTML Webpack Plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#options) options. Add the following to your `vue.config.js` file.

```js
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.plugin('html').tap((args) => {
      args[0].inject = false

      return args
    })
  }
```